# Visio reverse engineering

Tags: sqlite, visio

I am new with Visio. Is it possible to generate an empty database from a database scheme? I am trying to generate a SQLite database from a Visio database scheme. I have tried to use reverse engineering with different SQLite drivers but could never see any tables to select in the reverse engineer wizard......

BTW, Is there any other tools that could build a SQLite database easier? I tried SQLite Manager, SQLite2009 pro enterprise manager. Either of them seems to be very user friendly. Also tried OsenXP Suite which did not work at all either...

Answer (score 1):

Hope this could help

there is an answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3867566
seems you have to install ODBC driver

I've also tried using MySQL database, and need ODBC to connect to VISIO. The steps are here 
http://sajjadhossain.com/2009/02/12/reverse-engineering-mysql-database-with-microsoft-visio/

Maybe the step is same because using ODBC

Unfortunately, I found error, if the table name is longer than 16 characters, then the visio will error.